# TYPO3 Multiple addresses for Powermail

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x, powermail

I have a custom extension with 20 records.

Each record has a field of E-Mail.

How can I add all email address in powermail as the recipient.

This example gives me only one E-Mail address of this record in the details page.

```
plugin.tx_powermail{
settings.setup{

prefill{
mailadresses = RECORDS
mailadresses {
source.data = GP:tx_myext_list|example
source.insertData=1
source.intval = 1
tables=tx_myext_domain_model_example
conf{
tx_myext_domain_model_example>
tx_myext_domain_model_example=TEXT
tx_myext_domain_model_example{
field=email
htmlSpecialChars = 1
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution. Or can there be problems?

```
 lib.multimail = CONTENT
 lib.multimail {
 #Welche Tabelle
 table = tx_myext_domain_model_example
 select {
 #PID/Ordner
 pidInList = 10
 #andWhere {
 #  value = 1=1
 #}
 andWhere = hidden=0
 #andWhere =  deleted=0
 }
 renderObj = TEXT
 #Name des Tags in der Tabelle
 renderObj.field = email
 renderObj.wrap = |,
 }
```

In receiver by Powermail:

```
{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.multimail')}
```

Thanks for the help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

so `GP:tx_myext_list|example` is an comma separated list of uids from your models? Otherwise it return only one. If it a comma separated list, `intval = 1` will make it to only one integer and remove the list.

Also `insertData = 1` is not needed because you use `data =`.